# How to remove strings with the same length except one in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an Enumerable string sequence ordered by length of strings (all string are in upper case). How can I order this sequence alphabetically and then remove all strings with the same length, except one in each length group in LINQ?

E.g.:
`ORIEW DRERE EWKD OPPA LTS ERS YT GL HF`
should be
`DRERE EWKD ERS GL`

Comment: Just curiosity, why have you accepted that answer when there is another one which exactly returns what you expect?

Comment: @I4V I'm just trying to use methods of 1st answer, adding some more functions to that resolution and I got exactly what I want. I voted up all answers, because all of them are acceptable for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have elements defined as:

```
string[] elements = new[]
           {
               "ORIEW",
               "DRERE",
               "EWKD",
               "OPPA",
               "LTS",
               "ERS",
               "YT",
               "GL",
               "HF"
           };
```

Then you can use:

```
var result = elements.OrderBy(r => r)
                    .GroupBy(r => r.Length)
                    .Select(grp => grp.First());
```

For output you can use:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

and you will get back:

```
DRERE
ERS
EWKD
GL
```

*(remember with the order by you should get `ERS` before `EWKD` - Not like in question)*

Comment: `var elements = "ORIEW DRERE EWKD OPPA LTS ERS YT GL HF".Split(" ".ToCharArray());`

Comment: @NickC, the OP has in question "I have an Enumerable string sequence ordered by length ...."

Comment: I noticed that sentence after I had already posted my comment.

Answer (score 3):

you could do this:

```
var myStrings = "ORIEW DRERE EWKD OPPA LTS ERS YT GL HF".Split(' ');

var myGroups = myStrings
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Length);

var result = myGroups
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .OrderBy(x => x.Length); // Or OrderByDescending if order is important.
```

`result` will contain:

```
GL 
ERS 
EWKD 
DRERE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var res1 = list.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
               .ThenBy(s => s)
               .GroupBy(s => s.Length)
               .Select(s => s.First())
               .ToList();
```

or using [DistinctBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) of morelinq

```
var res2 = list.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
               .ThenBy(s => s)
               .DistinctBy(s => s.Length)
               .ToList();
```

**List's content:**

```
DRERE 
EWKD 
ERS 
GL
```

if you input is not a `List<string>` but a string then you can form the `list` as

```
string input = "ORIEW DRERE EWKD OPPA LTS ERS YT GL HF";
var list = input.Split();
```